# log4j.properties works for eclipse, but causes errors for intellij

Tags: eclipse, intellij-idea, log4j

Here's my log4j file:

```
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, A1, ERROR, A1
#Direct log messages to a log file
log4j.appender.A1.File=/place/logs/applog/dashboard.log
log4j.appender.A1.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.A1.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c:%L %t- %m%n
log4j.appender.console=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.console.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.console.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ABSOLUTE} %5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
log4j.logger.org.springframework.cache=DEBUG
log4j.logger.net.sf.ehcache=TRACE
```

Here's the error that intellij throws, but not eclipse

```
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/usr/local/Cellar/tomcat/8.0.26/libexec/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.6.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/usr/local/Cellar/tomcat/8.0.26/libexec/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/lib/slf4j-simple-1.7.5.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory]
log4j:ERROR Could not find value for key log4j.appender.A1
log4j:ERROR Could not instantiate appender named "A1".
log4j:ERROR Could not find value for key log4j.appender.ERROR
log4j:ERROR Could not instantiate appender named "ERROR".
log4j:ERROR Could not find value for key log4j.appender.A1
log4j:ERROR Could not instantiate appender named "A1".
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
```

I'm not to familiar with log4j, so explain this to me like I'm 5. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

It has been awhile since I fooled with log4j configuration, but in your rootlogger line why do you define A1 twice?  I thought the pattern for that property was:

default log level, list of appenders applicable to root

so in your case:

```
rootLogger = INFO, console, A1
```

Comment: That seemed to fix it actually. I didn't think the IDE had any effect on this.

Comment: good deal - yep wasn't sure if that was the issue why IDE would make a difference.

Answer (score 0):

Using IntelliJ IDEA Step 1: Put on first line in your main method

```
BasicConfigurator.configure();
```

Step 2: Go to help > Edit custom properties and insert the code

```
log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG, A1
log4j.appender.A1=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.A1.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.A1.layout.ConversionPattern=%-4r [%t] %-5p %c %x - %m%n
```